# How to add color to canvas flashlight effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I was wondering if there is any way to add color effects to my flashlight in JavaScript so it looks kind of like a light on my images. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this effect that I want. I have tried to add all my code throughout my CSS, JavaScript, and HTML, but so far I just have the effect of the mouseover circle. I am not sure if it is even possible to add the effects of making a color happen over the flashlight effect, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Snippet** - Here is my JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  const canvas = document.getElementById("flashlight-canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const image = document.getElementById("darkimage");

  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  let radius = 150;
  let mouseX, mouseY;

  function drawFlashlight() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    drawFlashlight();
  });

  drawFlashlight()
  
});
```

```css
#flashlight-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1000px
}

#darkimage {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 1000px
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="week5">
  <h2>Week 5</h2>
  <p>Canvas</p>
  <div class="container5">
    <canvas id="flashlight-canvas"></canvas>
    <img src="https://3.api.artsmia.org/800/109833.jpg" id="darkimage" alt="Dark Image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this help? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient

Comment: I don't see a flashlight effect in the code at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your code, I did not bother to find out what and just rewrote.

### Draw a flashlight FX

One (of many) ways to do a flash light FX with color is to use a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient).

Then draw that gradient over the image to light using one or more of the additive composition modes. (in example I use `"color-dodge"` and `"lighter"`)

You can use global alpha to mix the strength of composition modes, and set the radial gradient color stops to the color of the light.

### Example

Example loads an image and creates a gradient for the light. Note image is only in code, not on the page as HTML

When the image has loaded (MUST! WAIT FOR IMAGE TO LOAD) the canvas size is set to match the image and the `draw` function is set to draw the FX.

I don't know how much color or the strength of the FX you want to add so I just use a little red and yellow and mixed in a medium composition mode

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var draw = () => {}; // does nothing until image has loaded

// create image 
const image = new Image;
image.src = "https://3.api.artsmia.org/800/109833.jpg";
image.addEventListener("load", () => {
  draw = drawFlashlight;
  canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
  draw();
}, {once: true});

var radius = 150, mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

// create gradient for light
const lightGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, radius);
lightGrad.addColorStop(0.0, "#705545");
lightGrad.addColorStop(0.2, "#765");
lightGrad.addColorStop(0.4, "#706555");
lightGrad.addColorStop(0.92, "#504433");
lightGrad.addColorStop(0.97, "#100800");
lightGrad.addColorStop(1.0, "#000");

function drawImage(image) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

function drawFlashlight() {
  ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  drawImage(image);
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, mouseX, mouseY);
  ctx.fillStyle = lightGrad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  ctx.fill();
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  draw();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```